# expression 'string' cannot be used as an assignment target -SQL PLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, procedure

I wrote the following procedure which was meant to be anonymous and remove all the vowels from a string, but when I call it I get an error: I've followed the advice given in a similar post, but it didn't help:[Oracle PLS-00363: expression '' cannot be used as an assignment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977229/oracle-pls-00363-expression-cannot-be-used-as-an-assignment-target)

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE disemvowel (string IN OUT NVARCHAR2)
2  IS
3  BEGIN
4  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(translate(string,'euioa',''));
5  END disemvowel;
6  /

Procedure created.
```

So good so far, but now I call it:

```
SQL> BEGIN
2  disemvowel('hahahahaha');
3  END;
4  /
```

The Error message says:

```
disemvowel('hahahahaha');
           *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PLS-00363: expression 'hahahahaha' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: As you are not changing the passed parameter there is no need to define it as `IN OUT`. Just `IN` is enough and then you can pass a constant as well

Comment: I like the procedure name :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your procedure has IN OUT parameter. So while calling the procedure you should [supply a variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#BABFHBBC) to it, so that it can hold the value that the procedure gives back. You cannot supply a value directly, as it cannot be modified by the procedure.

```
DECLARE
   param   NVARCHAR2 (20) := 'hahahahaha';
BEGIN
   disemvowel (param);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate new VARCHAR2 type variable to assign your IN (input) string.

```
PROCEDURE sp_name(
ps_list              IN VARCHAR2,
...
write here other IN's and OUT's
...
)
AS

ps_list_copy          VARCHAR2 (32000); 

BEGIN
ps_list_copy := ps_list;
...
do your works with ps_list_copy
...
...
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
....
END sp_name;
```