# Handling error in binding variables Oracle/PHP

Tags: php, oracle, parameters, bind

I am trying to output the error message if the query had an error, here's my code:

```
class app {

    private $db;
    private $con;
    private $err;
    ...
```

---

```
public function addNewRelative($parentId, $name, $relationCode, $relation, $phone, $email) {

    $sql = "BEGIN XXDM_DSQUARE_PKG.CREATE_CONTACTS(
                :P_SUBJECT_PARTY_ID,
                :P_OBJECT_PARTY_NAME',
                :P_RELATIONSHIP_CODE,
                :P_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE,
                :P_MOBILE_NUMBER,
                :P_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                :X_ERROR_MSG
            ); END;";            

    //Statement does not change
    $stmt = oci_parse($this->con, $sql);

    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_SUBJECT_PARTY_ID', $parentId);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_OBJECT_PARTY_NAME', $name);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_RELATIONSHIP_CODE', $relationCode);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE', $relation);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_MOBILE_NUMBER', $phone);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_EMAIL_ADDRESS', $email);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':X_ERROR_MSG', $this->err);

    // Execute the statement as in your first try
    if (oci_execute($stmt)) {
        return json_encode(["response"=>1]);
    } else {
        return json_encode(["response"=>0]);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 8, column 6: PLS-00363: expression '&lt;null&gt;' cannot be used as an assignment target ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in D:\Server\wamp\www\dmg-dsquares-bk\app.php on line 94
```

The problem is with ‘X_ERROR_MSG’ parameter, as it’s OUT parameter, and I don’t know how to bind it.

Comment: Is that really the correct way of passing variables to a stored procedure in Oracle? Shouldn't it just be: `BEGIN xxxxx('first', 'second', ....); END;`? Or better yet: `BEGIN xxxx(:first, :second, ...); END;` and bind the values. At least [according to Oracles docs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, both would work, but yours is more secure, and is what I did in second try.

Comment: But now you're doing `P_SUBJECT_PARTY_ID=>{$parentId}` (which looks weird) instead of either just `{$parentId}` or `:parentId`. Also, since your title is "error in binding", you should probably show the code where you use parameter bindings. The posted code has nothing to do with bindings. Please update the question to show the binding attempts.

Comment: Where do you set `$this->err`? Shouldn't it be `oci_error($this->con)`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, just updated my answer.

Comment: @Barmar, see the updates.

Comment: Googling this error message indicates that it happens when the procedure tries to assign to a parameter variable that's declared `IN` rather than `OUT`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977229/oracle-pls-00363-expression-cannot-be-used-as-an-assignment-target for example

Comment: @Barmar it’s OUT parameter, for error handling.

Comment: If it's an out parameter, you need to provide an Oracle variable to be filled in, you can't use a bound parameter.

Comment: Are you trying to get it to store the result into the PHP variable `$this->err`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, exactly.

Comment: The example on https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html implies that this should work. Does it work if you use an ordinary variable instead of a class property?

Comment: @Barmar No, same error.

Comment: Does the procedure work if you call it by hand rather than from PHP?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, and working also from PHP but without error parameter.